# Unable to Interact with elements on Webview of ios 11 Hybrid App

Tags: appium, appium-ios

working on ios 11 with hybrid app with appium version 1.7 . I am able to switch the appium driver to webview succesfully and also when locating the element using xpath , I get element.isDispalyed as true and appium server logs also returns a element id when findelement command is fired but after that I am unable to click on the element

Answer (score -1):

There is a flag "clickable" in the UIAutomator. You should check if it is true or false.